# My AWS lambda function works local but not with sam start-lambda / start-api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, sam

Hopefully someone can help on this.
I've been trying to test my lambda online (I've manage to deploy it) But now I am getting the same error online as well as using sam local start-api or start-lambda.

It "works" when I run  docker run -p 9000:8080 myFunction:rapid-x86_64
I say "works" because I have my response like:

```
response = {'statusCode': 200,
                        'headers': {
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
                        },
                        'body': body_response
                        }
```

But using POSTMAN I get in the response body the whole response with "headers" which I think shouldn't.

Could this be the reason is not working online? In the event I only receive the body of the request, not the header... I haven't seen this in other functions.

Maybe you can see the resource for the function

```
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Events:
        InputEvent:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /input
            Method: post
            PayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"
      PackageType: Image
      MemorySize: 3008
      ImageUri: image:rapid-x86_64
      ImageConfig:
        EntryPoint: [ "python3", "lambda_function.py" ]
        WorkingDirectory: "/var/task/"
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./
      DockerTag: rapid-x86_64
```

The error on start-lambda:
[ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited without providing a reason InvokeID=

using docker run:
Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin)
But I get the whole response including the headers in the body response (why is not returning the correct headers in the response?)

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone faces a similar error, I would recommend switching to a serverless template.

Helpful resource was https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda

I was able to deploy my lambda without any issues.